# ¿cómo se puede usar el operador =>?

Tags: php

El operador `=>` se usa en php para generar arrays asociativos pero... ¿se usa ademas para acceder a propiedades en clases?
Lo comento por que al ver esto:

```
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET_NAMES ' . DB_CHAR
```

me da la impresión que así sea. Además del uso de declarar valores en arrays asociativos. ¿cómo se puede usar el operador `=>` ?

Comment: en que contexto has visto ese codigo? yo lo he encontrado en este stackoverflow: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807202/how-to-specify-collation-with-pdo-without-set-names?rq=1` y se esta usando en un array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es erróneo pensar que `=>` sirve para acceder a propiedades de una clase. No está definido así en PHP. [La documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php) indica con toda claridad que a las propiedades de una clase se accede mediante el operador de objeto `->` o mediante `::` si se tratase de una propiedad estática.

> Dentro de los métodos de una clase, se puede acceder a las propiedades
>   no estáticas utilizando `->` (el operador de objeto): `$this->propiedad`
>   (donde propiedad es el nombre de la propiedad). A las propiedades
>   estáticas se puede acceder utilizando :: (doble dos puntos):
>   `self::$propiedad`.

El ejemplo que muestras en tu pregunta se usa en un contexto de array, [como se puede ver en el **Ejemplo 1** del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). En PHP el operador **`=>`** se usa solamente pare asociar claves => valores en los arrays.

Quizá tu confusión venga porque precisamente PDO acepta en el constructor **un tercer parámetro en forma de array asociativo** donde puedes indicar otras configuraciones del objeto, como pueden ser el charset, el estado de las preparaciones emuladas, cómo se manejarán las excepciones, qué método fetch por defecto, etc, como bien explica [la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php):

> `options`
>
> Un array de la forma clave=>valor con opciones de conexión
>   específicas del controlador.

Cabe decir además que el uso de `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` que muestras es para versiones viejas de PHP (anteriores a 5.3.6), por lo que dice el mismo Manual:

> 5.3.6 Antes de la versión 5.3.6, charset era ignorado.

En versiones posteriores es más conveniente setear el charset directamente en el DSN, poniéndolo después del nombre de la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
$mPDO = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 4):

Aquí se juntan dos conceptos:

1- En primer lugar el operador `=>` lo que hace es indicar pertenencia en un Array asociativo o mejor dicho en una Hash Table (o tabla de hash).

Por ejemplo, este código:

```
$myArray = [
    'name' => 'Wolverine',
    'power' => 'healing factor'
];
```

Genera un array asociativo, con donde a la izquierda se indica el key y a la derecha el valor.

2- Propiedades estáticas.
Según OOP las clases pueden tener propiedades y métodos státicos. Estos pueden invocarse desde la clase misma sin necesidad de instanciar.

*Editado: PHP a su vez, permite tener **constantes** como propiedades de una clase, las cuales son públicas. Las mismas son públicas.*

Por ejemplo:

```
class Mutant {
    const PLANET = 'Earth'; //constante
    static $factor = 'x'; //propiedad estática
}


echo "Un mutante es del planeta: ".Mutant::PLANET." y tiene un factor: ".Mutant::$factor;
```

Mostrará el texto:

```
Un mutante es del planeta: Earth y tiene un factor: x
```

En definitiva en el código que consultas, **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND** es una constante de la clase PDO, la cual se utiliza para indicar el key en un array asociativo.

Comment: Podrias aclarar donde es que las clases (segun POO) con una propiedad constante (que es distinto a una estatica) pueden ser accedidas sin necesidad de una instancia? porque me suena a un error teorico grosero (tal vez php lo permita, pero no es cierto en otros lenguajes y no es un standard de la programacion orientada a objetos)

Comment: Tienes razón, veo que me he líado al momento de escribir. Ya mismo edito para que quede claro y no generar confusión (o no propagar un dato erróneo).